# Compiling in controller returns empty html without data in it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, return

I am working on angular. I was trying to compile an HTML, but at the end, it only returns an empty HTML structure without any data in it. but when I console.log "element[0]". I am able to see the required HTML.

How to return the HTML with data in it.

```
  function IpHtml(key) {
            var tooltipScope = $scope.$new(false); // inherit from parent, so we can use 'iptraffic.category' for header
            tooltipScope.key = key;

            var html = '<div class="toolTipTraffic">' +
                '<div class="head">' +
                ' <b ng-bind="iptraffic.category"></b>' +
                '</div>' +
                '    <hr>' +
                '    <table class="table toottipTableTraffic">' +
                '        <tr ng-repeat="vals in key">' + // ng-repeat here
                '            <td>IP</td>' +
                '            <td>' + ': {{vals}}' + '</td>' +
                '        </tr>' +
                '    </table>' +
                '</div>';

            var element = $compile(html)(tooltipScope);
            console.log(element[0])

            return element[0].outerHTML
        }
```

Comment: try an $apply an just make sure scope is passes corrected in $compile

Comment: actually, I am new to these, can You explain what you are trying to say @VinodLouis

Comment: @VinodLouis thanks. After using $apply .it is working fine

Comment: but make sure you use !$scope.$$phase condition else it will result in error when multiple digest cycle are in execution